# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: musicServiceProvider <- musicService <- MusicController

Tags: angularjs

I have trying to add a service to fetch data from API .
But its gives an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: musicServiceProvider <-
>   musicService <- MusicController"

**Controller**

```
(function (app) {
var MusicListController = function ($scope, musicService) {
    $scope.message = " Jagadish K M";
    musicService.getAll().then(function (response) {
        $scope.musics = response.data;
        console.log($scope.musics);
    });
  };
app.controller("MusicController", MusicListController);
    }(angular.module("theMusic")));
```

**Service**
(function (app) {

```
var musicService = function ($http, musicApiUrl) {
    var getAll = function () {
        return $http.get(musicApiUrl);
    };
    var get = function () {
        return $http.get(musicApiUrl);
    }
    var getById = function (id) {
        return $http.get(musicApiUrl + id);
    };

    var update = function (music) {
        return $http.put(musicApiUrl + music.id, music);
    };

    var create = function (music) {
        return $http.post(musicApiUrl, music);
    };

    var destroy = function (id) {
        return $http.delete(musicApiUrl + id);
    };

    return {
        getAll: getAll,
        getById: getById,
        update: update,
        create: create,
    };
};
app.factory("musicService", musicService);
}(angular.module("theMusic")));
```

I am newbie in angular. Thanks in advance

Comment: i have tried finding solutions but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: what is `musicApiUrl` in your factory signature ? Because if it's not a service, it should not be here. Only dependencies should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't inject your service.

```
angular.module("theMusic", ["musicService"])
```

You should take a look to **[AngularJS Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)** documentation.